# Cómo filtrar usando dos listas, sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Buen día, supongamos que tengo la siguiente tabla:

tabla
id1   id2   dato1   dato2
----   ----   -------    -------
1      a      d1a1    d2a1
1      b      d1b1    d2b1
2      a      d1a2    d2a2
2      b      d1b2    d2b2
3      a      d1a3    d2a3
3      c      d1c3    d2c3

y quiero obtener los valores `d1a1` y `d1b2`, por lo que uso el siguiente `query`:

```
SELECT dato1 FROM tabla WHERE id1 IN (1, 2) AND id2 IN ("a", "b");
```

pero esto me devuelve los datos: `d1a1`, `d1b1`, `d1a2` y `d1b2`.

¿Es posible que me devuelva los datos que yo quiero usando listas? Lo que necesitaría hacer es relacionar el primer elemento de la primer lista con el primero de la segunda lista y así sucesivamente

Acá dejo un [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/adccc0/2) para que tengan algo ya armado.

Comment: si ya sabes los valores que quieres consultar, no te valdría con algo de este tipo: SELECT dato1 FROM tabla1 WHERE dato1 in ( "d1a1","d1b2") ;

Comment: en este ejemplo si, pero en mi base real tengo demasiados datos y no los conozco como para buscar los datos, solo tengo el id1 y el id2, de esta forma vinculo tablas y obtengo todo. Este es un ejemplo simplificado.

Answer (score 0):

Estás filtrando id2 con "a" o "b" cuando las filas que pides son las dos "a". Con la siguiente consulta obtendrías `d1a1 y d1a2`:

```
SELECT dato1 FROM tabla1 WHERE id1 in (1, 2) AND id2 in ("a");
```

Comment: perdón, ahí edité la consulta. quiero que me devuelva d1b2

Answer (score 0):

Conociendo solo los datos de las columnas `id1` e `id2` para obtener los valores de `d1a1` y `d1b2` necesitas agregar un `OR` según el tipo de valor en  `id1` e `id2`:

```
SELECT dato1 FROM tabla WHERE id1 IN (1) AND id2 IN ("a") OR id1 IN (2) AND id2 IN ("b");
```